Issues with Jest Testing in Quasar Template with Vue 3 and Vite
I'm creating a template to work with Quasar Framework, Vue 3, and Vite where the goal is to clone the project and develop the frontend without extensive configurations since everything should already be set up. So far, I've made decent progress. However, recently I implemented a security module (I know, better safe than sorry). When I tried running the tests, I encountered the following error:

> jest

 PASS  src/testing/unit/strings.test.js
 FAIL  src/testing/unit/security.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/debian/Documentos/projects/vue/quasar_template/src/helpers/security.js:17
      const key = _cryptoJs.default.enc.Utf8.parse(import.meta.env.VITE_AES_KEY);
                                                          ^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

    > 1 | import { setNewPassword } from '../../helpers/security'
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | describe('Security Helper', () => {
      4 |   test('Set a secure form to send the password. (`setNewPassword`)', () => {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.require (src/testing/unit/security.test.js:1:1)

 PASS  src/testing/unit/numbers.test.js
 PASS  src/testing/unit/rules.test.js

Test Suites: 1 failed, 3 passed, 4 total
Tests:       19 passed, 19 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.784 s
Ran all test suites.

I've researched this issue, but nothing seems to work.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "quasar-template",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.6.4",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.html",
  "description": "This is a template for quickly working with Quasar and Vite - Vue 3. It includes features that assist in both individual and group workflows, such as Husky for Git hooks, Prettier for code formatting, and ESLint for code quality checks. Additionally, it provides testing capabilities with Jest, along with Axios for HTTP requests, Crypto-js for cryptography functionalities, and Jwt-decode for JWT decoding. It also integrates Pinia for state management and Vue-router for routing. The template utilizes Sass for styling and supports TypeScript. Furthermore, it implements lint-staged for staged linting, and vue-eslint-parser for parsing Vue files within ESLint. Notably, it supports internationalization throughout the app, facilitating efficient adaptation of content and user interface to different languages via tools like vue-i18n, thus extending the application's reach to a broader audience.",
  "keywords": [
    "Quasar",
    "Vite",
    "Vue 3",
    "Husky",
    "Prettier",
    "ESLint",
    "Jest",
    "Axios",
    "Crypto-js",
    "Jwt-decode",
    "Pinia",
    "Vue-router",
    "Babel",
    "Testing-library",
    "Sass",
    "TypeScript",
    "lint-staged",
    "vue-eslint-parser"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Santiago1010/quasar-template.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Santiago1010/quasar-template/issues"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Santiago Correa Aguirre",
    "email": "santiago.c.a_10@hotmail.es"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build",
    "dev": "vite",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "format:check": "prettier --check \"{public,src}/**/*.{js,ts,vue,json,css}\"",
    "format:write": "prettier --write \"{public,src}/**/*.{js,ts,vue,json,css}\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:check": "eslint \"{public,src}/**/*.{js,ts,vue,json}\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint \"{public,src}/**/*.{js,ts,vue,json}\" --fix",
    "prepare": "husky || true",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:integrations": "jest ./src/testing/integration",
    "test:unit": "jest ./src/testing/unit"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,ts,vue}": [
      "prettier --write --ignore-unknown",
      "eslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^4.0.0",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.9",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "quasar": "^2.14.5",
    "vue": "^3.3.11",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.9.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.10",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^8.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^29.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.23.0",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.33.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.8",
    "vite-plugin-environment": "^1.1.3",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^9.4.2"
  }
}

This is my ./jest.config.json:
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js|ts)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["vue", "js"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/", "/tests/"],
  "coverageReporters": ["text", "json-summary"],
  "testEnvironmentOptions": {
    "customExportConditions": ["node", "node-addons"]
  }
}

This is my ./babel.config.json:
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta"
  ],
  "env

": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

And this is my ./vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 5173,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),

    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: './src/config/i18n',
    }),

    quasar({
      sassVariables: './public/styles/sass/quasar-variables.sass',
    }),

    EnvironmentPlugin('all'),
  ],
})

This is my security.js:
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

/**
 * Encodes a string using AES encryption.
 *
 * @param {string} string - The string to be encoded.
 * @return {string} The encrypted string.
 */
const encodeAes = (string) => {
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(import.meta.env.VITE_AES_KEY)
  const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(import.meta.env.VITE_AES_IV)

  return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, key, { iv }).toString()
}

/**
 * Encodes a given string using SHA256 algorithm.
 *
 * @param {string} string - The string to be encoded.
 * @return {string} The encoded string.
 */
const encodeSHA256 = (string) => {
  return CryptoJS.SHA256(string).toString()
}

/**
 * Encodes a string using SHA256 and AES algorithms.
 *
 * @param {string} string - The string to be encoded.
 * @return {string} The encoded string.
 */
const setNewPassword = (string) => {
  return encodeSHA256(encodeAes(string))
}

/**
 * Validates a JWT session token.
 *
 * @param {string} [incomingToken=null] - The incoming token to validate. If provided, it will overwrite the token stored in localStorage.
 * @throws {Error} If no token is found in localStorage or if the JWT_SECRET is not defined in the .env file.
 * @throws {Error} If the JWT has expired or if the issuer or audience is invalid in production or pre-production environments.
 * @return {Object} An object with the following properties:
 *   - valid: A boolean indicating whether the token is valid or not.
 *   - payload: The decoded payload of the token.
 *   - token: The stored token.
 */
const validateSessionJwt = (incomingToken = null) => {
  try {
    const localStorageTokenName = import.meta.env.VITE_LOCAL_STORAGE_TOKEN_NAME // Name of the key in localStorage

    let storedToken = localStorage.getItem(localStorageTokenName) // Get token stored in localStorage

    // If a new token is provided, overwrite the stored token
    if (incomingToken) {
      storedToken = incomingToken
      localStorage.setItem(localStorageTokenName, storedToken) // Store the new token in localStorage
    }

    if (!storedToken) {
      throw new Error('No token found')
    }

    const decodedIncomingToken = jwt.decode(storedToken, { complete: true })

    // Validate JWT signature (secret key should come from a secure environment)
    const secretKey = import.meta.env.VITE_JWT_SECRET
    if (!secretKey) {
      throw new Error('JWT_SECRET is not defined in the .env file')
    }

    jwt.verify(storedToken, secretKey)

    // Additional validation (e.g., expiration) only in production or pre-production environments
    const isProductionOrPreProduction =
      import.meta.env.VITE_NODE_ENV === 'production' ||
      import.meta.env.VITE_NODE_ENV === 'pre-production'

    if (isProductionOrPreProduction) {
      const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

      // Check expiration date (exp)
      if (decodedIncomingToken.payload.exp && decodedIncomingToken.payload.exp < now) {
        throw new Error('JWT has expired')
      }

      // Check issuer (iss) if required
      const expectedIssuer = import.meta.env.VITE_JWT_ISSUER
      if (expectedIssuer && decodedIncomingToken.payload.iss !== expectedIssuer) {
        throw new Error('Invalid issuer in JWT')
      }

      // Check audience (aud) if required
      const expectedAudience = import.meta.env.VITE_JWT_AUDIENCE
      if (expectedAudience && decodedIncomingToken.payload.aud !== expectedAudience) {
        throw new Error('Invalid audience in JWT')
      }
    }

    return {
      valid: true,
      payload: decodedIncomingToken.payload,
      token: storedToken,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error validating JWT:', error.message)
    return {
      valid: false,
      payload: null,
    }
  }
}

export { setNewPassword, validateSessionJwt }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Please, I haven't been able to solve it, and all the solutions I've found break the rest of the application.

Please don't post issues as screenshots of the console

Ok. I'm sorry. I already edited it to display the error in code format as well.
